# How to check data send to a PHP page via JSON?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I need to check the data in target `php page` that is sent by `JSON` when I click `add to basket button` in `OpenCart 3`.

How it's possible to do this check in php page for example using `print_r`?
Or is there any better way to do this check?

It's a normal JSON code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product' + id + ' input[type=\'hidden\'], #product' + id + ' input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked'),
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
```

PHP Codes:

```
public function add() {
    $json = array();

    if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = (int)$this->request->post['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

    if ($product_info) {
        if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
            $quantity = (int)$this->request->post['quantity'];
        } else {
            $quantity = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['option'])) {
            $option = array_filter($this->request->post['option']);
        } else {
            $option = array();
        }

        $product_options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->post['product_id']);

        foreach ($product_options as $product_option) {
            if ($product_option['required'] && empty($option[$product_option['product_option_id']])) {
                $json['error']['option'][$product_option['product_option_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_required'), $product_option['name']);
            }
        }

        if (!$json) {
            $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

            $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

            // ...
```

Many thanks for any kind help.

Comment: you can use `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));` and it will print the json which is posted to your php file.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to find the content that is posted in json to the php file. Just use below line

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Then decode json

```
$dec = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($dec); // this prints the array
```

Comment: Thanks Rama! But I'm sorry, I don't know where should I put this code!

Comment: I putted just after `public function add() {`, but it shows `unexpected end of JSON...' error.

Comment: put this on top of your file after php tags.

Comment: something it needs to be print on your response on your browser console. Do one thing put this line on top of your code `file_put_contents('test.dat', file_get_contents('php://input'));` and it creates a file test.data and check the response inside the file.

Comment: I checked like this and helped me to fix the problem: console.log($('#hdn input[type=\'hidden\'], #product' + id + ' input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked')); 
 Many thanks for your helps anyway!